# What does it mean "adjoin A to B"?

Tags: abstract-algebra, terminology

What does it mean that we can obtain $\mathbb{C}$ from $\mathbb{R}$ by adjoining $i$?

Or that we can also adjoin $\sqrt{2}$ to $\mathbb{Q}$ to get $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})=\{a+b \sqrt{2}\mid a,b \in \mathbb{Q}\}$?

Comment: [Please see here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020/264) for a guide to writing math with MathJax, and [see here](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) for a guide to formatting posts with Markdown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means exactly what you have written there. Let $F$ be a field and $\alpha$ be a root of a polynomial $f(x)$ that is irreducible of degree $d$ over $F[x]$. Then we say we can adjoin $\alpha$ to $F$ by considering all linear combinations of field elements of $F$ with scalar multiples of powers of $\alpha$ up to $d-1$, or rather:

$F(\alpha) = \{a_{1} + a_{2}\alpha + a_{3} \alpha^{2} + \cdots + a_{d}\alpha^{d-1}| a_{1},\ldots,a_{d} \in F\}$.

Note that because $\alpha \notin F$ because it is a root of an *irreducible* polynomial in $F[x]$. However, $F(\alpha)$ certainly contains $\alpha$. In this light, we can view field extensions as a way of "extending" base fields to include elements they wouldn't otherwise have.

You'll notice this is consistent with the definition of $\mathbb{C}$ from $\mathbb{R}$. $i$ is the root of the irreducible polynomial $x^{2} + 1$ over $\mathbb{R}[x]$. Hence, if we define $\mathbb{C} = \mathbb{R}(i)$, then

$\mathbb{C} = \{a + bi | a, b \in \mathbb{R}\}$.

Comment: You do not necessarily end up with a set like $\{a+b\alpha:a,b\in F\}$. Consider adjoining $\sqrt[3]2$ to $\mathbb Q$.

Comment: @user1, I have updated my post accordingly. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

"Adjoin" generally means "find the smallest (field / ring / favorite object) extension containing the object that we're adjoining." So the very smallest field that contains both $\mathbb{R}$ and $i$ is in fact $\mathbb{C}$, and $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{2}]$ denotes the smallest field extension of $\mathbb{Q}$ containing $\sqrt{2}$.

Comment: I think this reply from @user61527 should have been accepted as the official answer as it's clear, self-contained (not relying on other concepts such as irreducible of degree d over F[x]), and therefore easy to understand...